# SQL - Is using 2 Dates in my WHERE clause redundant?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a query (that I run on an Oracle DB) which looks something like:

```
SELECT 
Column1,Column2,Column3 FROM MyDatabase.MyTableName 
WHERE 
(DELETED = 0) 
AND (DATESEEN > TO_DATE ('20/03/2013 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
AND (DATERECORDED  >= TO_DATE('20/06/2013 06:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) 
AND (DATERECORDED < TO_DATE('20/06/2013 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

The query is dynamically generated, the dynamic values are as follows:

The second line of the where clause (DATESEEN) is 90 days ago.
The third line of the where clause is the time the query last ran. (Usually 12 hours ago)
The last line of the where clause is the time now.

There is not an index on DATERECORDED, but there is on DATESEEN. I'm not able to put an index on DATERECORDED, for reasons beyond my control.

Is my "DATESEEN" line **in my WHERE clause** totally redundant? As the DATESEEN is always going to be a date much before the DATERECORDED, will it be disregarded? The execution plan reveals very little:
[image: Execution Plan]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the CAPUTREDATE line? As to why no index is used although there is one on DATESEEN it's probably a statistics question. If the statistics are up to date, Oracle seems to believe that the condition is not restrictive enough and that it isn't worth using rather than making a full table scan.

Comment: Are you using dateseen just for index purpose  or do you really need it ?

Comment: @jods DATESEEN - not CAPTUREDATE, my apologies. Getting my DB's muddled up! Edited. Not sure re how old the statistics are, and the access I have (again, beyond my control!) doesn't let me check - I'll ask the question. Thanks.

Comment: @loki - DATESEEN is one of the columns needed, and is in the select statement. DATERECORDED isn't in in the 'select' part. Thanks.

Comment: What's the table partitioned on? As for "is it redundant", how could we tell exactly?

Comment: Just try to run the query with only dateseen in where and see if index is used? If not then it can be stale stats issue else optmizer is ignoring it.

Comment: @Mat, sorry, table partitioning is still a new concept to me, I believe it is partitioning on the DATESEEN. I've clarified what I mean by 'redundant'.

Comment: @loki, stats were last gathered on 14th June, I believe they run weekly. Changed the query to only use DATESEEN, and it still did a full table scan. Think I'm getting somewhere now - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an index on `DateRecorded`.  In order to satisfy the `where` clause, Oracle would need to do a full table scan, reading all the records.

An index can prevent a full table scan -- either an index on `deleted` or an index on `DateSeen` (because you have ruled out the index on `DateRecorded`).

If there are no indexes on these two fields, then the clause is redundant.  If there are, it could significantly reduce the I/O of the query.  Not as much as having an index on DateRecorded, but it could be a lot -- especially if you have 10 or 20 years worth of data.

However, Oracle is free to not use such an index.  The decision is based on the statistics collected about the table.

Another consideration would be partitioning.  If the table is partitioned by `DateSeen`, then having it in the `where` clause allows the database to choose the right partition(s) to satisfy the query.  This would not be possible using other columns.

Comment: Thanks for this Gordon. DateSeen has an index, but, based on the execution plan, I dont think it's being used. I'm guessing it's in there so the optimiser can look at the correct table partition. Who'd have known there was so much to a table?! Thank you for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
AND (DATERECORDED  >= TO_DATE('20/06/2013 06:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

is not redundant because it adds additional filtering.

This line:

```
AND (DATERECORDED < TO_DATE('20/06/2013 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

might be redundant.  If the daterecorded is always in the past and you are always checking for less than the current date, it is.

Your dateseen line may or may not be redundant.  If it adds filtering or speeds up the query, it is not.  Otherwise, it si.

Comment: Dan, thanks for this. The second line is always going to be "the time now". I'm not sure if the dateseen line will add any filtering, as the date in daterecorded will always be > than the one in dateseen - that's my question. :). I'm not sure if it'll be using that index, or just disregard it and focus on the other 2 dates in the clause.